# How to change button text in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

That's memory game.
I put there only one button but i have 27 buttons so how to randomly change the text when i click that?
code :

```
from tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()
name = root.title('Pexeso')
text = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
button1 = Button(root, text="", width = 20, height = 10)
button1.grid(row=0 , column=0)
def button_click():
    if button1["text"]=="":
        button1["text"] = random.choice(text)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have a look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829890/tkinter-with-python-3-3-change-colour-of-button-on-click

Comment: You haven't bind a command for your button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()
name = root.title('Pexeso')
text = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
def button_click():
    button1["text"] = random.choice(text)
button1 = Button(root, text="", width = 20, height = 10, command=button_click)
button1.grid(row=0 , column=0)

root.mainloop()
```